# IIS web.config Error - HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I'm unable to resolve the error `HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error`. I've installed donet 3.1 hosting bundle and url rewrite module as suggested by other answers.

Any idea what the issue is? I've spend a lot of hours and still couldn't fix it.

[image]

`Error:`

```
Detailed Error Information:
Module     IIS Web Core
Notification       Unknown
Handler    Not yet determined
Error Code     0x8007000d
Config Error       
Config File    \\?\C:\catalog\web.config

Config Source:
   -1: 
    0:
```

`XML:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\catalog.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. From the [downloads page of donet](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/3.1) I downloaded the aspnetcore-runtime instead of the hosting bundle.

[image]

After downloading the `hosting bundle` and installing it, everything works fine.

[image]